Langchain csvloader - how can i parse multiple columns?
I have a csv which has format as follows

I need to parse this into a txt file whilst keeping a dictionary format. I use langchain:
loader = CSVLoader(file_path='test.csv', encoding="utf-8",csv_args={'delimiter': ','} )
loader.load()

however i get this error:
    f"{k.strip()}: {v.strip() if v is not None else v}"
       ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'


It seems like it might not be formatted correctly. Can you try exporting it to excel and share a df.head()?
